# Integral closures and quasi-finite morphisms between curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ and $Y$ be affine curves defined over $\mathbb{C}$ and suppose $f \colon X \to Y$ is a dominant regular map which is quasifinite, but not finite.

If $A = \mathbb{C}[X]$ and $B = \mathbb{C}[Y]$ are coordinate rings, then the integral closure $C$ of  $f^\ast (B )$ in $A$ is a proper subring of $A$, since $f$ is not finite.

My main question: Can we guarantee that $C$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra?

I was hoping that this would follow easily from Finiteness of Integral Closure (Thm 3.9A in Hartshorne) and/or Zariski's Main Theorem, but I can't seem to make it happen.

More generally, what can we say about $C$ in this situation? With such a vague question, references would be appreciated.

Comment: If you mean by an affine curve, spec of a finitely generated algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ (of dimension one), this is correct. Why doesn't it follow from Hartshorne? I do not have a copy handy, but this is proved in Zariski-Samuel, Matsumura and any number of other books.

Comment: @Mohan If $K$ and $L$ are the fraction fields of $A$ and $ B $ respectively, the result I want to use in Hartshorne requires $K$ to be a finite extension of $L$.  Since $f$ is not a finite morphism, this is not the case.

Comment: If $K\subset L$ fields, finitely generated over say $\mathbb{C}$ and have the same transcendence degree, then the the extension is finite. In your case, the function fields have both transcendence degree 1 and they are finitely generated over complex numbers. So, the result applies. Finiteness of the morphism $f$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Oh, you're totally right.  I was being dense - thanks for clearing that up for me!